# name 'tqdm_notebook' is not defined

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, tqdm

I am trying to use the tqdm_notebook function but I am getting an error even after checking the installation of tqdm and ipywidgets.

```
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
for param in tqdm_notebook(parameters_list):
# we need try-except because on some combinations model fails to converge
    try:
        model=sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(data, order=(param[0], d, param[1]),
        seasonal_order=(param[2], D, param[3], s)).fit(disp=-1)
    except:
        continue
aic = model.aic
# saving best model, AIC and parameters
if aic < best_aic:
    best_model = model
best_aic = aic
best_param = param
results.append([param, model.aic])
```

The errors shown is,

```
 NameError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-33-277a561b8f50> in <module>
      1 from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
----> 2 for param in tqdm_notebook(parameters_list):
      3 # we need try-except because on some combinations model fails to converge
      4     try:
      5         model=sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(data, order=(param[0], d, param[1]),

NameError: name 'tqdm_notebook' is not defined.
```

I have tried with pip install tqdm, pip install ipywidgets and jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension.
Everything looks fine but I am getting this error, how to rectify this.

Answer (score 1):

The correct import is

```py
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
```

See **Advanced Usage** section at their [github repository](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm)

Also you've assigned `tqdm_notebook` to be `tqdm`.

Comment: I have used that import also but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try

```
from tqdm import *
```

Comment: I have used that but I am getting a new error,

`NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-0146ed8d5138> in <module>
      9     aic = model.aic
     10 # saving best model, AIC and parameters
---> 11 if aic < best_aic:
     12     best_model = model
     13 best_aic = aic

NameError: name 'aic' is not defined`

But I have used all these imports

`import statsmodels.api as sm from statsmodels.tsa.stattools
 import adfuller from pandas.plotting 
import autocorrelation_plot from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA`

Comment: can you remove your first try except block? There is some error being hidden there.

Comment: @ac24, remove means what can I do instead of that ??  kindly give me an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Your code probably has an error when defining `model`, hence the name error that follows. However, because this code is in a bare `except:` block, this error is not getting raised, `model` is not getting defined, etc.

Instead of this:

```py
    try:
        model=sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(data, order=(param[0], d, param[1]),
        seasonal_order=(param[2], D, param[3], s)).fit(disp=-1)
    except:
        continue
```

use this code:

```py
   model=sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(data, order=(param[0], d, param[1]),
   seasonal_order=(param[2], D, param[3], s)).fit(disp=-1)
```

and then see what different error results.

Comment: I am getting an error like this `ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).` if I use these lines

Comment: Kindly have a look here, [link](https://deepnote.com/project/Untitled-Python-Project-D6jNHahzTyCIYd_OcsM0bw/%2FArima.ipynb)

Comment: OK so your pandas dtypes in `data` aren't suitable for the sarimax model. Check them using `data.dtypes` and then convert any that need to be numeric using `pd.to_numeric`

Comment: Kindly can you direct me where I should do this, I cannot understand